# Is there anything in-game pointing to the location of the Hylian Shield?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I'm playing Breath of the Wild, trying to finally finish up the quests I never got around to before. I'm trying to play as spoiler-free as possible, so I'm not looking up the locations of things, but I do know that the hylian shield exists in the game and would like to get it. Is there anything in the game that directs you to the hylian shield? A quest that leads to it, or even just an NPC who says "I saw some fancy blue shield in this place"?

Note: I *do not* want to be told where the shield is. I want to be told where *some hint pointing towards the shield* is.

Comment: Closely related: [Is there a reason to buy shields from Russ?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/322073/is-there-a-reason-to-buy-shields-from-russ) The link has the same quote I mentioned, but without spoiler tag. I'm not VTC as dup because the questions are different

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is! If you buy all three shields from [Russ](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Russ) the shield surfer, he will drop a hit to the location of the Hylian Shield. He is located in the Eldin Canyon below a tree by the Trilby Plain.

For completeness sake, I am adding the actual quote from Russ into the answer with a spoiler tag.

> That shield right there won't easily break, that's for sure. Oh! Speaking of not breaking, have ya heard about the Hylian shield? Everyone in the surfing scene covets that bad boy. It's clearly commissioned by the royal family or somethin'! Its sturdiness makes it perfect for shield surfing too. You don't really see 'em around these days...but rumor has it there's one in Hyrule Castle. Though no one has ever gone there and returned in one piece...
>
> <sub>[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/axrc4o/question_about_the_hylian_shield_and_quests/)</sub>

Comment: And the hint is far from a give-away; it will still take plenty of playing without looking it up to get it!

Comment: @GendoIkari Exactly. Unless you just happen to find it on a whim, it can still be tricky to locate

Comment: I still remember the moment when I first found it the first time I played (having been given no outside information about where it would be)... so exciting.

Comment: @GendoIkari Can confirm, it took quite a while to actually find it! That place is a maze, quite literally.

Comment: You don't actually have to purchase all three shields, you only have to purchase the third shield (Knight's Shield). I purchased the one shield and got the same tip about the Hylian Shield.